# How to undo column aggregation on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with columns that are an aggregation of corona virus cases over time.

[image: Data Table]

I need the data in the date columns to be the new number of cases for that day instead of the aggregation. 
So for example, I am trying to get the first row to be like

```
Anhui, Mainland China, 1, 8, 6
```

I think there might be a quick pandas way to do this but can't find it by google searching. A brute force method would be okay too. Thanks!

Comment: how do you compute 8 and 6?

Comment: 15 - 9 = 6
9 - 1 = 8
@Datanovice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take take the finite difference along constant rows in the dataframe. If df is a copy of the numerical part of the dataframe then the following will do it:

```
df.diff(axis=1)
```

[Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html)